# Get all vertex in JgraphT

Tags: jgrapht

In jgrapht, I have added some vertex.

I wanted to know how to get all vertex that I have added or already exist in jgrapht ?

Is there a way to get it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give all the vertex in the graph.

```
DefaultDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Node, DefaultEdge>(
            DefaultEdge.class)
directedGraph.vertexSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use what Anto Livish's answer if you just have a graph
If you create a GraphPath (like a shortest path), you can use getVertexList() and store them in a list